# Programa compilado em Delphi não abre

Tags: delphi, compilação, debug, processo, release

Boa tarde,

tenho um software escrito em Delphi e notei que ocorre o seguinte problema:

Se utilizo a opção de compilar no modo debug, o executável fica com 32MB e funciona corretamente.

Se utilizo a opção de compilar no modo release, o executável fica com 9MB, inicia o processo no windows mas não abre.

Alguém sabe me dizer quais as diferenças e o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Quando você tenta executar o `.exe` ele retorna alguma `exception`

Comment: Não retorna nada, apenas abre o processo no gerenciador de tarefas mas o sistema nao exibe nenhuma tela.

Comment: Certo, como você está tratando as exceções?

Comment: com try / except

Comment: Isso acontece se você criar um projeto em branco também? Verifica se tem alguma diretiva forçando uma diferença entre debug/release, e posta o código do .dpr, onde ele dá o star da application, só para verificar.

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema. Inclusive com projetos novos e em branco (só o form principal vazio)!!!! O executável é gerado mas não roda, e o seu tamanho (12MB) não é normal para um form vazio.

Answer (score -3):

Pode ser que no debug ele coloque alguma dll, units ou componente que ele não esta colocando no release. Tente executar em um programa que não tenha o delphi instalado e ele vai te dizer algumas dll que estão faltando.
Ou deixe as duas configurações iguais.